# How to foreach following xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

I have following xml result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1254" ?>
<RESPONSE>
  <VALIDATION>1</VALIDATION>
  <QUERY1 searched="12345">0</QUERY1>
  <QUERY2 searched="aaaaa">2</QUERY2>
  <QUERY3 searched="44444">2</QUERY3>
  <QUERY4 searched="99999">0</QUERY4>
  <QUERY5 searched="number">0</QUERY5>
  <QUERY6 searched="bar">0</QUERY6>
  <QUERY7 searched="foo">1</QUERY7>
</RESPONSE>
</xml>
```

I have following class

```
public class Result{
 public string SearchValue {get;set;}
 public string SearchResult {get;set;}
}
```

And this code

```
...
List<Result> r = new List<Result>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResult);
foreach( var item in doc.Descendants("RESPONSE")){
 r.Add(new Result{
   SearchValue = item.Attribute("searched").Value,
   SearchResult = item.Element("QUERY?").Value
 });
}
...
```

How to get all searched keys and searched result to list object?

Comment: Your code is currently looking for all XML elements called `RESPONSE`. I suspect that's not what you actually want - there's only one such element, which is more simply accessed as `doc.Root`. Were you expecting `item.Element("QUERY?")` to somehow perform a wild-card search?

Comment: What's that `</xml>` doing there, btw? If that's actually in your text, it's not valid XML...

Comment: I want to add all possible query1, query2, query(n) objects to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert it to a json object and use Linq

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlResult);
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc));

    List<Result> results = ((JObject)jObj["RESPONSE"]).Properties()
               .Where(v => v.Name.StartsWith("QUERY"))
               .Select(v => new Result
               {
                   SearchValue = (string)v.Value["@searched"],
                   SearchResult = (string)v.Value["#text"]
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why convert to JSON when LINQ to XML still allows you to query with LINQ, without getting JSON involved?

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I just don't know how to use  Linq to Xml and don't see much sense to learn it.  Last time I used XML about 20 years ago.

Comment: Thank you! all of worked! Have a nice days.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* you want something like:

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResult);
var results = doc.Root
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("QUERY"))
    .Select(e => new Result {
        SearchValue = (string) e.Attribute("searched"),
        SearchResult = e.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

That assumes that:

- You only care about elements that are direct children of the root element
- You want to ignore any elements whose local names don't start with "QUERY"
- You're okay with handling a missing `searched` attribute by creating a `Result` object with a null value for `SearchValue`
- You're okay with `SearchResult` being the concatenation of all text nodes in the query element

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet ! Its worked as expected!

Answer (score 1):

You can select the descending elements using xpath `//RESPONSE/*[starts-with(name(),'QUERY')]`

```
    foreach(XmlNode row in doc.SelectNodes("//RESPONSE/*[starts-with(name(),'QUERY')]"))
    {
        if(row.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Any(x=>x.Name=="searched"))
        {
            Result r2 = new Result(){
                SearchValue = row.Attributes["searched"].Value,
                SearchResult = row.InnerText
            };
            r.Add(r2);
        }
    }
```

LINQ rewrite

```
    var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//RESPONSE/*[starts-with(name(),'QUERY')]")
                    .Cast<XmlNode>();
                    //.SelectMany(x=>x.ChildNodes.Cast<System.Xml.XmlElement>());
    var query = (from elm in nodes
                where elm.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Any(x=>x.Name=="searched")
                select new Result(){
                    SearchValue = elm.Attributes["searched"].Value,
                    SearchResult = elm.InnerText
                }).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RMxEiT

Comment: This is a much more complex approach than using LINQ to XML IMO.

Comment: Thank you! Its worked as expected!

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe XPath is faster than LINQ to XML

Comment: `doc.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("QUERY"))` checks all the elements vs XPath simply navigates to that path, even if looks complex it performs well

Comment: @NitinSawant: Is there *any* indication that performance is important here? In the absence of any requirement, I'd definitely suggest using the simplest approach - and I'd say LINQ to XML wins hands-down there. (I'd also actually be somewhat surprised if XPath was faster in this particular case, but I don't think it's worth even benchmarking without any evidence that performance is a concern.)